# When creating a .NET Standard Class Library in VS 2017 RC, how should I keep package references as private implementation details?

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

For example, here's my .csproj right now:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" ToolsVersion="15.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.3;net451</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="**\*.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.resx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="1.50.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NETStandard.Library" Version="1.6.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Nothing from Dapper will be exposed in the public API, so it seems like I should keep it as a private implementation detail. But when creating a test .nupkg and referencing it from a .NET Framework Console App, the app gains a reference to Dapper.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `PrivateAssets` flag:

```
<PackageReference Include="Dapper">
  <Version>1.50.2</Version>
  <PrivateAssets>Runtime</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

From the [docs](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/PackageReference-Specification) (which could probably use some clarification):

> ... these can include any of the following values:
>
> - Compile – are the contents of the lib folder available to compile against
> - Runtime – are the contents of the runtime folder distributed
> - ContentFiles – are the contents of the contentfiles folder used
> - Build  – do the props/targets in the build folder get used
> - Native - are the contents from native assets copied to the output folder for runtime
> - Analyzers – do the analyzers get used
>
> Or, instead:
>
> - None – none of those things get used
> - All – all of those things get
>     used.

Comment: This is useful because it does hide the dependency, but when doing `msbuild /t:pack` I don't see Dapper assemblies or anything else about Dapper in the .nupkg. Searching for PrivateAssets led me to [this link](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/PackageReference-Specification) which seems like it might be useful. This is my first time trying to make a NuGet package, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I think then runtime, might be the appropriate value for you.